# Returning the Results as well as subscribing in Meteor Mongo Geosearch

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Using Meteor.js I've got the following code for my pub/sub working flawlessly. I'm able to pass my arguments through and return the cursors with no problem.

My objective is to display the distance between the current user location and the database result.

As mongodb has already calculated the distance to get the result set I don't want to calculate it again someplace else. I'd like to return the geoNear.results[n].dis results of the $geoNear documented [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/geoNear/#output) but can't work out a practical way to go about it. I appreciate the publish only returns a cursor to the docs but wondered if there was some way to attach the results somehow...

```
Meteor.publishComposite("public", function(location, distance) {
return {
find: function() {
      return Tutors.find({},
                  {
                    $geoNear: {
                        $geometry: {
                          type: "Point" ,
                          coordinates: [ location.lng , location.lat ]
                        },
                        $maxDistance: distance,
                      },
                    }
                  );
                }
}
});
```

My subscribe arguments are simply a lat/lng object and distance in metres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if I told you that you could use Mongo **[aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)**? The general idea here is to get the distance between the current user location and the database result to update automatically with a change in the `'Tutors'` collection, thus use **[`publication`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish)** with an observe to achieve this.

Here's the set-up. The first step is to get the aggregation framework package which wraps up some Mongo methods for you. Just `meteor add meteorhacks:aggregate` and you should be home and dry. This will add an **[`aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/)** method to your collections.

An alternative to adding the aggregation framework support is to call directly your mongoDB and access the underlying collection methods, which in this case you need the **[`aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/)** method. So, use this to connect in the mongoDB :

```
var db = MongoInternals.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver().mongo.db,
    Tutors = db.collection("tutors");
```

Now you can dive into the aggregation framework and build up your pipeline queries. The following example demonstrates how to get the aggregation in the publish reactive use a **[`observe`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/observe_changes)** in the publish with **[`ES6 in Meteor`](https://medium.com/@dferber90/es6-in-meteor-5e088c998e4a#.d37h8ltec)**.  This follows the `'counts-by-room'` **[example](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish)** in the meteor docs. With the **[`observe`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/observe_changes)**, you know if a new location has been added, changes or removed. For simplicity re-run the aggregation each time (except remove) and if the location was previously published then **[`update`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/publish_changed)** the publish, if the location was removed then **[`remove`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/publish_removed)** the location from the publish and then for a new location use **[`added`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/publish_added)**:

```
Meteor.publish('findNearestTutors', function(opts) {
    let initializing = 1, run = (action) => {
        // Define the aggregation pipeline
        let pipeline = [
            {
                $geoNear: {
                    near: {type: 'Point', coordinates: [Number(opts.lng), Number(opts.lat)]},
                    distanceField: 'distance',
                    maxDistance: opts.distance,
                    spherical: true,
                    sort: -1
                }
            }
        ]
        Tutors.aggregate(pipeline).forEach((location) => {
            // Add each of the results to the subscription.
            this[action]('nearest-locations', location._id, location)
            this.ready()
        })
    }

    // Run the aggregation initially to add some data to your aggregation collection
    run('added')

    // Track any changes on the collection you are going to use for aggregation
    let handle = Tutors.find({}).observeChanges({
        added(id) {
          // observeChanges only returns after the initial `added` callbacks
          // have run. Until then, you don't want to send a lot of
          // `self.changed()` messages - hence tracking the
          // `initializing` state.
          if (initializing && initializing--)
            run('changed')
        },
        removed(id) {
            run('changed')
        },
        changed(id) {
            run('changed')
        },
        error(err) {
            throw new Meteor.Error("Houston, we've got a problem here!", err.message)
        }
    })

    // Stop observing the cursor when client unsubs.
    // Stopping a subscription automatically takes
    // care of sending the client any removed messages.
    this.onStop(function () {
        handle.stop();
    })
})
```

Comment: Awesome. You nailed it!